# program called twice from the command line

Tags: shell, command-line, python, command

Let's say I have a (Python3) script of my own named `myscript`; for various reasons, `myscript` (**not** `myscript.py`) is stored in a sub-directory named `bin` :

```
mydir/
mydir/bin/
mydir/bin/myscript       -rwxr-xr-x
```

`myscript` begins with the [usual shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take), namely :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

When I'm in `mydir/`, I call my script this way:

```
$ ./bin/myscript
```

The result is tantalizing (to me !), `myscript` being called twice ! I get something like:

```
sh: 1: myscript: not found
*** specific message defined in myscript ***
```

The first line is clearly a sign that the shell tries to find a command named `myscript`. The second line is what I wrote in `myscript`.

**Why is my script called twice ?**

Comment: I'm assuming something inside the script is trying to execute something called `myscript` using `system()` (or whatever other similar facility Python has), but fails.

Comment: Could you provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kusalananda mentioned that it's possible your script is calling `myscript` using `system()`. When you call with `system` I would guess the containing directory of `myscript` is not in the `$PATH` variable of the shell at that point, so you would need to pass the full path of `myscript`, not the relative path.

Comment: You're 100% right... My script checks if it's already installed by calling... `os.system(myscript --version)`...